# How to create a Global connectionstring to SQL Server Database for my SharePoint site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007, web-config

This is my connection string inside my web.config of my SharePoint site.
Its sitting just below the closing SharePoint tag.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SAMRASConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=JOHANDEVVM;
        Initial Catalog=samrasDB; User ID=Johan; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Where must i place it in order to get a Global Connectionstring.

Reason be: When i go to my IIS site Properties -> ASP.NET tab -> Edit Global Configuration
Then the connection string is not there, its only by the Edit Configuration.

I need it to be there to access it from other client computers. I need to change it in my web.config file and dont want to go add it manually on the Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the connectionString in Machine.Config if you have access to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an SPWebConfigModification in a feature reciever to add web.config modifications to all servers in a farm.

http://www.crsw.com/mark/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=32

Comment: Link is dead and no longer useful. Please post all necessary information in the answer itself.